# Rails - Global Variables to be used anywhere, including controller, views, and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

My question is seemingly simple but has been pretty elusive.  I want one value that can be called anywhere in the application - it's a minimum value we are using for validations in the model, we want to inform the user of that value, etc.

So far, I have done the following:

In config/initializers, I created a new .rb file (under suggestion I found on another thread):

```
minimum = 15
```

and only got that it couldn't be found after starting rails server.

I found a strange suggestion to put the value in en.yml as minimum: 15, same issue as above.

Obviously, application helper and controller won't help as I need the value in my models.  I did however find one solution, which was to put it in the class Application in config/application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
    ::Minimum = 15
end
```

and afterwards call it like this:

```
MyApp::Application::Minimum
```

Obviously, this solution, while it does work, isn't ideal.  If I could find a way to alias MyApp::Application::Minimum as just "minimum", I'll be completely satisfied, but getting it done in the initializers is, from what I've heard, a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick something in a model if you want and call it from anywhere:

```
Couriers = %w[TNT UPS RoyalMail Bike Hand Pigeon Other]
```

But I prefer putting them in a yaml file.

Create a config.yml file in your configs directory and put your vars in there:

```
defaults: &defaults

   node_1: '10.8'
   node_2: '10.9'
   node_3: '10.0'

   whatever: 1
   thereis: 2

development:
  <<: *defaults

playground:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults

poststaging:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults
```

Load the config file using something like this in your initializers directory. Create a file in /config/initializers called 'load_vars.rb' and put the following in there:

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

You'll have to restart your server after changing these though.

-- EDIT --

To use these variables, you can load with something like this from your model, controller, views:

```
SETTINGS['var_1']
```

Comment: Sorry, but I've never really loaded YAML files from initializers before.  I made a single file in config/initializers with just this line (the path to config.yml is the same in mine), and I'm getting "cannot convert string to hash"

Comment: Following my method or your own you get this error? You need a file called 'static_vars.rb' in your initializer dir with the last bit in.

Comment: I was following my own for config.yml, so I did the following: Copied your first file word-for-word into config/config.yml, but changed the "whatever thereis" to min_val: 0.  In static_vars.rb and later load_vars.rb, I pasted what you posted above.  In my model, I had validates :var, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => min_val}.  When I tried starting my server, min_val could not be found in the model.

Comment: Ah sorry, I will update my answer. You need to load the vars slightly differently.

Comment: On this, I just found what was going wrong with initializers before, in that I didn't know the values had to be all caps.  This just means I can use MINIMUM = 0.  You wouldn't happen to know any way to let it be so that the variable can be lower case, would you?

Comment: The variable or the variable name?

Comment: Does it matter that much? I can't see why using uppercase would cause problems - you could try it with lower case if you wanted. Using settings = might work but I haven't tried it. S

Comment: It doesn't, but I wanted to see if there was any chance I could.  This worked well enough.  I'm accepting your answer now.

Comment: I don't think it will work lower case. Just tried. Thanks and good luck. S